# Android Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

Right now I am trying to create an activity with an EditText and a button, and below that a listview were I can Dynamically add strings to the list. I'm getting errors trying to mock up my activity.

**Here is my main activity.**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Connection serverConnection;
private ArrayList<String> listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, 0, listItems);
    listview.setAdapter(adapter);
    serverConnection = new Connection(MainActivity.this);

}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void displayMessage(String string) {
     listItems.add(string);
     adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

}

}
```

**Here is the xml for the main activity.**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/message_entry"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/list"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send_button"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:hint="@string/enter_message" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/message_entry"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/message_entry"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/list"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/message_entry" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Here is my other class that I'm going to use to for connecting to a socket.**

```
public class Connection extends Thread {

private Socket client; 
private ObjectOutputStream output;
private ObjectInputStream input;

public Connection(MainActivity mainActivity) {


    mainActivity.displayMessage("Test1");
    mainActivity.displayMessage("Test2");       
    mainActivity.displayMessage("Test3");
    mainActivity.displayMessage("Test4");
    mainActivity.displayMessage("Test5");


}
}
```

Comment: 05-22 00:31:09.657: E/AndroidRuntime(23598): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 00:31:09.657: E/AndroidRuntime(23598): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
05-22 00:31:09.657: E/AndroidRuntime(23598):  at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1026)
05-22 00:31:09.657: E/AndroidRuntime(23598):  at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2131)
05-22 00:31:09.657: E/AndroidRuntime(23598):  at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:865)

Comment: Something wrong in building project. Try delete bin and gen folder and clean-build.

Comment: clean your project & try again...

Answer (score 6):

This line gives you an error

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, 0, listItems);
```

The second parameter accepts layout resourceID where you can populate the value (String) to the layout.

You can use the layout of android framework which is `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listItems);
```